# A needle,2$l$ long($l<a$),is thrown on the plane at random.Find the probability that the needle will hit any of the lines.

Tags: probability, geometry

A plane is ruled with parallel straight lines at equal distances of $2a.$A needle,2$l$ long($l<a$),is thrown on the plane at random.Find the probability that the needle will hit any of the lines.

I tried to solve.Since question is saying probability that the needle will hit any of the lines,i found probability that needle hits none of the lines and then subtracted this from $1$.Probability$=1-\frac{\pi l^2}{2l\times 2a}$.But this is wrong answer,correct answer is $\frac{2l}{\pi a}$.What should be the correct method to solve this question?

Comment: check out Buffon's Needle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle

Comment: I saw a fascinating solution to this problem using just expectations and considering the "needle" to be any polygonal line. Lost the reference, sorry. But I'd suggest to keep digging, there are many interesting solutions to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought that this would be a duplicate, but of all the questions related to Buffon's needle none seems to be asking straightforward for this derivation and none of the answers seems to provide one; and the Wikipedia article makes it look far more complicated than it needs to be; so here's a simple derivation:

I'll replace $2l$ and $2a$ by $l$ and $a$ for simplicity. If the needle forms an angle $\phi$ with the direction of the lines, its width perpendicular to the lines is $l\sin\phi$, so its probability to hit a line is the proportion $l\sin\phi/a$. Then averaging over $\phi\in[0,\frac\pi2]$ yields

$$
\frac{\int_0^\frac\pi2\mathrm d\phi l\sin\phi/a}{\int_0^\frac\pi2\mathrm d\phi}=\frac{l/a}{\pi/2}=\frac{2l}{a\pi}\;.
$$

Comment: Superb,simple and to the point derivation.@joriki